# Why does this code not throw an error when run in Net Beans IDE 8.0.1?

Tags: php

Here, I am sending output information before `header()` function. Note I have not used `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` to start and end the buffer.
And the following are the settings for my "`php.ini`" file for "`output_buffering`" :-

```
;   output_buffering
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: 4096
;   Production Value: 4096

<h1> Hi </h1>
<?php
    $redirect = false;
    if($redirect == true){
        header('Location: http://www.google.com');   
    }
?>
```

It just shows "Hi" with `<h1>` size and DOES NOT THROW AN ERROR LIKE :-

```
Warning: "Headers already sent" or "Cannot modify header information"
```

Comment: ($redirect = false) != true. Your condition is never fulfilled.

Comment: This code is similar to what is given in www.php.net from "header" topic. Basically, we are not supposed to send any html output before sending any header().

Comment: Hey guys a similar code is given in the following link :- php.net/manual/en/function.header.php . But when I run it in my Net Beans 8.0.1 , it does not throw an error

Comment: What part of "your condition is never fulfilled" do you not understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you're not sending any header because the if condition is not satisfied, so it won't throw any error.

Comment: This code is similar to what is given in www.php.net from "header" topic. Basically, we are not supposed to send any html output before sending any header()

Comment: Hey guys a similar code is given in the following link :- php.net/manual/en/function.header.php . But when I run it in my Net Beans 8.0.1 , it does not throw an error